# Show Items even if 0 rows with group by

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the query below to show for each item for each store the amount of each of 4 items we have.
It works great, and I created the temporary table to try to increase speed but my problem is that if the table has no rows for a certain product that product does not show up at all.

I'd like to show all four products(prodNo) regardless of if there is actually any of rows for that specific store.

I researched this site and could not find something similar enough for me to figure it out.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_invoice_dates AS
(
    SELECT Invoice_detail.del_date,invoice_Detail.StoreNo,mast_stores.SDesc, invoice_Detail.ProdNo,sold_qty,retn_price,retn_qty,sold_price FROM Invoice_detail 
        LEFT JOIN mast_stores on invoice_detail.StoreNO=mast_stores.Snum 
        LEFT  JOIN invoice on invoice_detail.Del_Date=invoice.Del_Date and invoice_detail.Invoice_No=invoice.Invoice_No  
        WHERE Cnum IN ('200','210') AND invoice_detail.Del_Date >= "2016-03-01" AND invoice_detail.Del_Date < "2016-04-01"
);

SELECT 
    temp_invoice_dates.StoreNo,
    temp_invoice_dates.SDesc,
    DATE_FORMAT(temp_invoice_dates.Del_Date,'%Y') as Year,
    DATE_FORMAT(temp_invoice_dates.Del_Date,'%M') as Month,
    temp_invoice_dates.ProdNo,
    mast_items.IDesc,
    SUM(sold_qty) as TotalIn,
    SUM(retn_qty) as TotalOut,
    ROUND(SUM((sold_qty*sold_price)-(retn_qty*retn_price)),2) as NetSales,
    CONCAT(ROUND(SUM(retn_qty)/SUM(sold_qty),2)*100,'%') as StalePerc
    FROM mast_Items 
    LEFT JOIN temp_invoice_dates on temp_invoice_dates.ProdNo=mast_items.Inum 
    WHERE mast_items.Inum in ('3502','3512','4162','4182')
    GROUP BY temp_invoice_dates.StoreNo, ProdNo
    ORDER BY temp_invoice_dates.StoreNo, ProdNo;

Drop table temp_invoice_dates;
```

Results are similar to:

```
StoreNo  Product  Count....  
1        1        1
1        2        5
1        3        2
1        4        1
2        1        14
2        2        1
2        4        4
3        2        33
3        3        3
```

Where as I'd like it to be

```
StoreNo  Product  Count ....  
1        1        1
1        2        5
1        3        2
1        4        1
2        1        14
2        2        1
2        3        0
2        4        4
3        1        0
3        2        33
3        3        3
3        4        0
```

Comment: Is there another table holding the master list of `StoreNo` values?

Comment: mast_stores has all the storeNo information, the key(unfortunately) is stored as snum, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT sp.StoreNo, sp.ProdNo
    , ...stuff...
    , sp.IDesc, sp.SDesc
    , ...more stuff...
FROM (
   SELECT i.Inum AS ProdNo, s.Snum AS StoreNo
        , i.IDesc, s.SDesc
   FROM mast_Items AS i, mast_stores AS s
   WHERE i.Inum IN ('3502','3512','4162','4182')
   ) AS sp
LEFT JOIN temp_invoice_dates AS tid 
   ON sp.ProdNo = tid.ProdNo 
   AND sp.StoreNo = tid.StoreNo
GROUP BY sp.StoreNo, sp.ProdNo
ORDER BY sp.StoreNo, sp.ProdNo
;
```

Normally I recommend against cross joins (as seen in the subquery) but in this case it is exactly what is needed. If the query is slow, you can instead insert the subquery results into a temp table beforehand, index that, and then use the temp table in place of the subquery.

*(Edit: should use `sp` fields when available for grouping and results)*

Comment: Got it with a tad bit of tweaking! Thanks(I just needed to add the constraint  AND s.Cnum IN ('200','210') to the cross join query.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I didn't notice that condition in the earlier query (and/or couldn't determine which table it was from).